# Portable Lamp Circuit

Tags: lamp, portable

I would like to create a faulty circuit board for a portable light lamp. The original circuit board of the light lamp has a slightly different configuration. Here, pressing a button can turn on the illumination, pressing the button again switches to other LEDs, and pressing it a third time turns off the lamp. The lamp can be powered directly through a 12V DC-IN connection or through the built-in Lithium-Ion 18600 battery.

Here is the front side of the defective board. On the back side, there are JST connectors for connecting DC-In, Battery-In, and the button.

[image: Defect Circuit]

I have constructed my current circuit board based on a similar principle. The difference is that I can turn the power supply on and off through the lamp's battery using a slide switch connected via a JST connector. When the lamp is connected directly to the DC-IN port, the battery is charged, and it stays lit continuously. I have used a [Zener diode](https://maker.pro/custom/tutorial/what-is-deep-discharge-build-a-simple-circuit-to-protect-batteries) for over-discharge protection. The TPS2121 controls the power supply source, switching to DC-IN once it's connected. Finally, the MCP73831 regulates the battery charging.

[image]

I would like to know if my circuit design contains any major errors, as I have rarely designed my own circuit boards before ordering the board.

Comment: I'd say you've succeeded -- based on my reading of the TPS2121 datasheet, you definitely have created a faulty design! Also, your design has nothing whatsoever to do with the original design in the photograph, so what was the point of all that?

Comment: I wanted to replace the old circuit with mine only that the push button is replaced with a switch. What I have connected wrong with the TPS2121

Comment: Maybe edit this *I would like to create a **faulty** circuit board*

Comment: MCP73831: VSS can't be unconnected, nor PROG. See datasheet.

Comment: Thank you very much, I must have overlooked that. But just to clarify, I want to replace the defective board with my self-made.